# extjs: passing variable to FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers

I've got a function:

```
function saveToJ(feature) {
    var str = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(out_options).write(feature, true);
    str = str.replace(/,/g, ', ');
    strObj = Ext.decode(str);
    if(strObj.properties.name == null) {
        ...
    } else {
        if(!win) {
            win = new Ext.Window({
                title : "Edit",
                items : [editPanel],
                closeAction : 'hide'
            });
        }
        win.show();
        }
    }
}
```

and a panel:

```
var editPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    width : 400,
    defaults : {
        width : 230
    },
    defaultType : 'textfield',

    items : [{
        fieldLabel : 'Name',
        name : 'name',
        allowBlank : false,
    }],

    buttons : [editSaveBtn, editDeleteBtn]

});
```

what i want to do is to use `strObj.properties.name` as a `value` for the field on my panel.
but `value: strObj.properties.name` gives an error that `strObj` is undefined.

`strObj` is declared outside of the `saveToJ` function.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was simple, just use:

`editPanel.getForm().findField('name').setValue(strObj.properties.name);`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the strObj itself isn't null before you try and open the window?  You shouldn't have to pass it to the Ext.form to be able to use it if it's in scope already.  I'd use a debugger and make sure it's not already null.

Comment: thanks, helped me to understand. `strObj` is really null when `editPanel` is rendered, so i had to pass it.